# Loop only adding one result

Tags: for-loop

Situation:

For each customer, make a purchase, subtract inventory from seller, add money to sellers account.

```
    // for each customer
        for ($c = 1; $c <= $maxCustomers; $c++) {

            // decide what to buy
            $willBuy = rand('1','7');

            // buy indica
            if ($willBuy == '1') {

                // how many eights are they going to buy..
                $willSpend = rand('1', '4');

                if ($indicaPrice < $averageIndicaPrice) {

                    if ($indicaAvailable > $willSpend) {
                        // update products
                        $newIndica = $indicaAvailable - $willSpend;
                        update_user_meta($sellerID, 'Indica', $newIndica);  

                        // pay for purchase
                        $newCash = $cash + $indicaPrice;
                        update_user_meta($sellerID, 'cashOnHand', $newCash);    

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>#".$c."</td>";
                        if ($willSpend > "1") { echo "<td>".$willSpend." 8th's of Indica Flowers</td>"; }
                        else { echo "<td>".$willSpend." 8th of Indica Flowers</td>"; }
                        echo "<td>$".$indicaPrice * $willSpend."</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>#".$c."</td>";
                        echo "<td>Could not find anything they liked. No sale.</td>";
                        echo "<td>$0</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                }

            }
     }
```

Problem #1: In the 'update products' section, it's only updating for 1 loop result. If there is more than one customer who buys 'indica' it only update the indica meta value for 1 result, not for each result (ie, if 2 people buy 3 indica each, it will only subtract 3 indica not 6).

Problem #2: The same thing happens in the 'pay for purchase' section. It only updates the cash for one purchase, not for each purchase.

Answer (score 0):

You are never changing `$indicaAvailable` are you? Shouldn't you update it based on what was sold?

Comment: It is being updated: $indicaAvailable   = get_the_author_meta('Indica', $sellerID ); --- // update products
                        $newIndica = $indicaAvailable - $willSpend;
                        update_user_meta($sellerID, 'Indica', $newIndica);

Comment: But you are never calling `get_the_author_meta()` inside the loop, right?
This line will always have the same value (the one before the loop):
`if ($indicaPrice < $averageIndicaPrice) {`